# vue cli webpack breaks on IE10

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

Now I'm using vue-cli with webpack configuration and this is in trouble on Internet Explorer 10. The problem is webpack doesn't convert `let` or `const` to `var` and IE 10 doesn't support ES5 variable like `let` and `const`.

Below is `webpack.base.conf.js` code.

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill','./src/main.js'],

  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

And compiled code throws an error `SCRIPT1002` with below line on IE10.

> ...let a = ...

However, what I have known is that webpack basically transform `let` and `const` to `var` but, result does not. How can I force to transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is...** not `vue` itself, but package which is in `node_modules`. One of packages is not transpiled (in my case, `buefy` library) basically, so I have to transpile manually.

**Solution**

`webpack.base.conf.js`

- Add buefy to transpiling entry(As I know, vue-cli webpack ignores packages in node_modules for performance issues).

  ```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [/node_modules\/buefy/, resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
  },
  ```
- Add new alias for importing manually transpiled package.

  ```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'buefy$': resolve('node_modules/buefy/src'),
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: works for me. A note: const resolve = require('resolve'); 
path.resolve('src')